# Big - O: Why does $7x^2$ differ from $3x$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I'm in a Discrete Mathematics course and we are covering Big-O.

I know the following:

$f(x) = {a_{n}{x^n} + a_{n-1}{x^{n-1}} + ... + a_{1} + a_0}$  is $O(x^n)$ for any polynomial where $n >1$.

By this notion, I can also state the following:

For any polynomial $n$ to the degree $d$, if $d$ is positive, we say that $f(n)$ is $O(n^{d})$. By this, it follows that if $d > c > 1$, then $n^{c}$ is $O(n^{d})$.

Now I found that for $7x^{2}$ is $O(x^{3})$ for $x > 7$ by:

$x > 7$ => $x(x^{2}) > 7(x^{2})$ => $7(x^{2}) \leq x^{3}$ for $C=1$ and $k=7$ as witnesses.

Now in my textbook, there is an example that simply states $3(x)$ is $O(x)$ and I cannot understand why? If I use the above thereom for a polynomial, it makes sense; but then why doesn't that hold true for $7(x^{2})$?

Both $7(x^{2})$ and $3(x)$ are technically polynomials, so why is $7(x^{2})$ not $O(x^{2})$?

If I try the same method for $3(x)$ as I did with $7(x^{2})$:

$x> 3$ => $x(x) > 3(x)$ => $3(x) \leq x^{2}$

But this is clearly not true. Simply try x = 1 and we prove that $3(1) \leq (1)^{2}$ is false.

Comment: Look carefully at the definition of "$f$ is $O(g)$".

Comment: One example $x=1$ doesn't disprove belonging to an $O$ class. The class is defined saying that the inequality must be satisfied for all $x$ large enough. Moreover, the inequality is allowed to hold up to a multiplicative constant. Therefore to prove that $f\notin O(g)$ one would need to find a sequence of values $x_n\to\infty$ such that $|f(x)|/|g(x)|$ is unbounded.

Comment: In the step where you try the same method for $3x$ as you did with $7x^2$, you needed to impose the condition $x>3$ - you wrote it there yourself. Thus you cannot consider $x=1$ as a counterexample.

Comment: "why is $7x^2$ not $O(x^2)$?": but $7x^2$ **is** $O(x^2)$. We say $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ as $x\to\infty$ if there are constants $C$ and $x_0$ such that $f(x)\leq C\cdot g(x)$ for all $x>x_0$. Picking $C=8$ and $x_0=0$ suffices to show $7x^2$ is $O(x^2)$.

Comment: (Similarly, $3x$ is $O(x)$, as can be seen by picking, for example, $C=4$ and $x_0=0$.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic So I just need to find any $O(g(x))$? It could've been $O(x^{2})$ or $O(x^{3})$? Can you elaborate more on how $3x$ is $O(x)$? I'm still not sure how that's the case?

Comment: @pstatix: you seem to think that $f(x)$ must lie in only one big-oh class. This is common beginner's error. The function $7x^2$ is $O(x^k)$ for all $k\geq 2$. So it's $O(x^2)$, and $O(x^{2.1})$, and it's $O(x^3)$, and it's $O(x^{2017})$. You're reading the "is" in "$f$ is $O(g)$" incorrectly. The "is" here means "is an element of the set." I elaborated on $3x$ being $O(x)$ above. If someone says "given $f$, find a $g$ such that $f$ is $O(g)$," there are usually infinitely many answers, but there's also a natural "best" answer: leave off any coefficients, and try to find the *sharpest* bound.

Comment: (Similarly, if I asked you to find an $x$ such that $7\leq x$, there are infinitely many answers, but there is one best answer: the sharpest/best you can do is pick $x=7$, but you could've picked any $x$ bigger than $7$, too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is $7x^2$ not in $\mathcal O (x^2)$?

This is simply wrong. $7x^2$ is bounded from above by $Cx^2$, just take the constant $C = 8$, for example. Hence $7x^2$ is in $\mathcal O(x^2)$.

However, $7x^2$ is also in $\mathcal O (x^3)$, since it is *also* bounded from above by $Cx^3$ (for sufficiently large $x$).

Remember that big-O only takes about the behaviour when $x$ is sufficiently large, this is very important. For example $x^2 < x$ when $0<x<1$, however $x^2$ dominates $x$ as $x\to\infty.$

---

**Example.** Show that $3x$ is in $\mathcal O (x)$. This is true by definition if 
$$3x\leq Cx$$
for sufficiently large $x$ (i.e. for $x\geq x_0$). Here it holds for any $x_0$ and $C = 3$.

Comment: So either $O(x^{2})$ or $O(x^{3})$ is an acceptable answer? For $3x$, why would the book state it is $O(x)$ rather than $O(x^{2})$? Isn't $3x$ in $O(x^{2})$?

Comment: @pstatix Yes, $3x$ is both in $\mathcal O (x)$ and  $\mathcal O (x^2)$... and $\mathcal O (x^3)$, etc. The book probably states the smallest upper bound, hence $\mathcal O (x)$.